# I am getting 0, 0 of latitude and longitude on the press but on the second one it displays the latitude and longitude

Tags: php, android

So, I am sending the latitude and longitude on my database on a click of a button. But on the first press it will save on my database but it saves latitude to 0 and longitude to 0, but on the second click of the button it will saves the latitude and longitude. I don't know why that happens.

This is my LocationActivity.java

```
public void insert() {
    latitude.toString().trim();
    longitude.toString().trim();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

    if (location == null) {

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

    } else {
        currentLatitude = (float) location.getLatitude();
        currentLongitude = (float) location.getLongitude();


        Toast.makeText(this, currentLatitude + "," +currentLongitude + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(LocationActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(LocationActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put(lat, latitude);
            params.put(lng, longitude);


            return params;
        }

    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}





@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended ( int i){
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed (ConnectionResult connectionResult){

        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);

            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {

            Log.e("Error", "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged (Location location){
        currentLatitude = (float) location.getLatitude();
        currentLongitude = (float) location.getLongitude();

        Toast.makeText(this, currentLatitude + "," +currentLongitude + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

This is my php file where I send the latitude and longitude to my database.

```
<?php


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $lat = $_POST['lat'];
    $lng = $_POST['lng'];


    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_coordinates (lat,lng) VALUES ('$lat','$lng')";


    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        echo "Sent";
    }else{
        echo "Could not send";

    }
}else{
echo 'error';
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: where you updating **latitude** and **longitude** which you are putting in `Map<String,String> params`, im only seeing you updating **currentLatitude, currentLongitude**.

also **requestLocationUpdates** is a asynchronous request so you should make network request when you actually have location when **getLastLocation** returns null

Comment: What should I do? @Nishant Pardamwar? Can you help me?

Comment: How can I make a network request? Can you show me how to do it? @Nishant Pardamwar